# Cross Join MySQL Query with Counts

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with a MySQL query.  I have a table with two columns (usr_id and search_term) and with the following data.

1        term1
1        term2
2        term1
2        term2
2        term3
3        term2
3        term3
4        term1
4        term3

I need to be write a query to generate the a list of all the possible combinations of terms and report the total number of usr_id's where the combination occurs.

term1  term2  2
term1  term3  1
term2  term3  1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the number users that have any given pair of terms.  You have to be careful about not overcounting if a user uses a term more than once.

```
select t1.term as term1, t2.term as term2,
       count(distinct t1.usr_id) as num_users
from table t1 join
     table t2
     on t1.usr_id = t2.usr_id and t1.term <> t2.term
group by t1.term, t2.term;
```